# If statement automatically open a tab but still remain focused on the current tab - php

Tags: php

Currently I have this code:

```
if($t_link->link_type == 'Success')
echo "<a target='_blank' href='http://www.sample.com'> Success Link</a>";
else 
echo "<a  href='sample.com'> Failed</a>";
```

But this only open a new tab which it will be clicked, what I want is to automatically open a new tab but still remain to the current page.

Comment: I dont think you can do that with PHP. Try to use javascript and window.open for Success.

Answer (score -1):

```
if($t_link->link_type == 'Success')
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'function NewTab() {window.open("http://www.sample.com", "_blank");}'
echo '</script>';
echo '<button  onclick="NewTab()"> Success Link</button>';
else 
echo "<a  href='sample.com'> Failed</a>"
```